# Two extends classes, have object that inherit from each other, best practise?

Tags: java, interface, abstract, extends

I wanted to optimize the code to use "BDTO extends ADTO", instead of duplicating method any() in DForm and EForm create a new class abstract (CForm) and where to put logic methods any ().

How resolve duplicate method? How is best Practice?

```
public class ADTO {

    public String a;

    public String getA() {return a;}

    public void setA(String a) {this.a = a;}
}



public class BDTO extends ADTO{

    public String b;

    public String getB() {return b;}

    public void setB(String b) {this.b = b;}
}

public abstract class CForm {

    ADTO aDTO;

    //  BDTO bDTO;

    public ADTO getADTO() {return aDTO;}

    public void setADTO(ADTO aDTO){this.aDTO = aDTO;}

    //  public BDTO getbDTO() {return bDTO;}

    //  public void setbDTO(BDTO bDTO) {this.bDTO = bDTO;}


    public void any() {//
        aDTO.getA();    //
    }                   //
                        // how resolve duplicate method ?
    //public void any(){    // when i use only attribute aDTO and run any1() in EForm, aDTO is null
    //  bDTO.getA();    //
    //}

}

public class DForm extends CForm {

    public void anyD(){

        getADTO().setA("test");
        any(); // run method here is ok
    }

}


public class EForm extends CForm{

    //form using here any() and BDTO
    public void anyE(){
        getADTO().setA("test");
        any(); //run method here aDTO is null, why?
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you are asking? Is your code not working as intended?

Comment: I wanted to optimize the code to use "BDTO extends ADTO", instead of duplicating method any() in DForm and EForm create a new class abstract (CForm) and where to put logic methods any ().

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow duplicate methods (at least not like you would like).

What you could do however (and I think that is what you intended): You can make a single `any()` method that either randomly calls `aDTO.getA()` or `bDTO.getB()` or pick whichever is available and runs that one.

Your any() method could look like this (random):

```
public void any() {
    if(new Random().nextBoolean())
        aDTO.getA();
    else
        bDTO.getB();
}
```

Or like this (first available):

```
public void any() {
    if(aDTO != null)
        aDTO.getA();
    else if(bDTO != null)
        bDTO.getB()
}
```

Comment: @user3750157 so you want to have a abstract class that can have any implementation for the any() method? if so, just make the method abstract (no implementation) and have seperate classes implementing the abstract class and use their custom version of the any() method. If thats not the case I have no idea what you actually want to accomplish. Also: seing as both your classes are pretty much the same (other than the X in getX and setX [all types are the same]) why don't you just generalize into a single class in the first place (using get() and set(String))

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. previously, I had 
<pre><code>
public class DForm{ BDTO aDTO; public void any(){ aDTO.getA(); } //other use aDTO } public class EForm { BDTO bDTO; public void any(){ bDTO.getA(); } //other use bDTO }
<pre><code>
and now wants to move any() method to new abstract class